# Parameterized Types and Generic Classes

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am having trouble sending my arraylist as a param to a generic method. Any idea what im doing wrong here?

```
ArrayList<Integer> list50k = new ArrayList<>();
list50k.add(1);
list50k.add(5);
list50k.add(8);
list50k.add(7);

selectionSort(list50k); // error is in this line
```

I then try to send the array to the method and get an error.
here is the method:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void selectionSort(T[] list){...}
```

Comment: You should always post the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ArrayList<T>` is not an array, meaning it can't be converted to a `T[]`.

Your method signature could be `selectionSort(List<T>)` if you wanted to pass the `ArrayList`.

You could also convert the `ArrayList` to a `T[]` but the syntax for that is a little annoying in java and I don't recommended unless you really need an array.

Comment: Well im thinking that ill need the array, because i am sorting 50,000 integers

Comment: So you don't need the `ArrayList` at all? Where do you get the input from? Is the size known before you read it in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227553/java-selectionsort-generic-class
this is my new question

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
selectionSort(list50k.toArray(new Integer[list50k.size()]));
```

get `Integer[]` from `ArrayList<Integer>` to make it valid argument as per your method signature.